# Solving for variable using Euler's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on code that will solve equations for x that are in the form $x^a \equiv b \mod pq$. So far, I can get to the point where I have $g = \gcd (p-1, q-1)$ and so need to solve $ad \equiv1 \mod [(p-1)(q-1)/g]$ for d, in order to arrive at the final solution for $x$. I understand it in principle, but I'm just not sure how to go about it. (Apologies if this belongs in the computer science Stackexchange, I really wasn't sure which one to ask this question in)

edit: I understand how to computer modular inverses, using $a^{-1} \equiv a^{p-2} \mod p$, but I don't know how I can use that here.

Comment: What precisely are you not sure about, how tocompute modular inverses? (e.g. by the Extended Euclidean algorithm)

Comment: I know how to computer inverses already, using a different formula. I edited my question to explain.

Comment: Are you given that $a$ is corpime to $\,\phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)?\ \ $

Comment: Not that I can tell.

Comment: But that's necessary (and sufficient) for $a$ to be invertible mod $(p-1)(q-1)/g\,$ (typo: I omitted $g$ above)

Comment: I'll assume so then. The textbook isn't very clear.